# AutoMapper - TypeConverter: Is there any chance to access the destination property from ResolutionContext

Tags: automapper, .net-6.0

Currently I'm working with an Custom Type Converter class which worked good until a new issue appeared. (AutoMapper v11)

My Configuration:

```
cfg.CreateMap<string, MappedRelatedDataString>().ConvertUsing<MappedRelatedDataStringConverter>();
```

And the Converter class:

```
public class MappedRelatedDataStringConverter : ITypeConverter<string, MappedRelatedDataString>
{
    public MappedRelatedDataStringConverter()
    {
    }

    public MappedRelatedDataString Convert(string source, MappedRelatedDataString destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return MappedRelatedDataString.CreateFromMapper(source, destination, context);
    }
}
```

Now I digged through the passed context parameter,if it is possible to access the destination property of my mapping operation and noticed that there is no link to the member which is set up as mapping destination.
I hoped that it would be pretty easy to get access to the PropertyInfo.

Could anybody give me a hint how to get it working. The goal is to get access to some custom attributes (via PropertyInfo) on the destination side.

This is how my context instance looks during debugging:
[image: Watch]

Comment: You have access to that in `ForMember(d=>d.Prop, o=>{ o.DestinationMember ...})`.

Comment: Ok, thank you - that confirms, what I was afraid from. I was quite glad that I came so far with my minimal configuration of AutoMapper, because everything worked great without configuring on member level. So I wanted to know, if there could be another option for me.

Comment: What are you trying to do with those attributes? Because it's _you_ who wants to access members, not AM :)

Comment: I primary want to try to pull out the information about the mapped source member when it gets flattened by AutoMapper

e.g.: Order.Customer.Name => OrderDto.CustomerName

While Order.Customer.Name is a primitve string on my DTO CustomerName is an object which should get of course the string value, but also the information that Customer.Name has been flattened.

Comment: That sounds a lot like a problem nobody should have :) But I guess it's possible with `ForAllPropertyMaps` and a resolver that takes the destination property.